# Gameobject moving oddly

Tags: unity-game-engine

My gameobjects are moving oddly.

On the enemy, I have this script :

```
public float speed = 1.0f;
private Transform target;

public void Start()
{
    var player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
    target = player.transform;
}

void Update()
{
    // Move our position a step closer to the target.
    float step = speed * Time.deltaTime; // calculate distance to move
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);

    // Check if the position of the cube and sphere are approximately equal.
    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position) < 0.001f)
    {
        // Swap the position of the cylinder.
        target.position *= -1.0f;
    }
}
```

After I hit the enemy with a projectile, it starts moving slower. The script behind the projectile is this :

```
    if (coll.gameObject.tag != "Player")
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);

        if ((coll.collider.GetComponent("Damageable") as Damageable) != null)
        {
            var d = coll.collider.GetComponent<Damageable>();
            d.Damage(1);
        }
    }
```

I added this script in, as a Damageable component, however, this behavior was there even before this script was active, so I don't think it's related :

```
public void Damage(int damageAmount)
{
    print("Damage : " + Health + ":" + damageAmount);
    Health -= damageAmount;
    if (Health <= 0)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Any recommendations on what is wrong?

Comment: One: you should cache the players transform in a method outside of `Update`, so that it's not called every single time. Two: when you say "it" moves oddly, are you referring to the player, the projectile, or the enemy hit?

Comment: Yeah, I initially did that. I had it in the start, then kept it in the class. Did the above cause I thought it might be due to something that "lost" the player's position, and that if I recalculated the position every time, it might fix it. Sadly, it wasn't the problem. Ill revert, and update the question.

Comment: since Vector3 is a struct, you won't lose reference to it from `player.transform`

Comment: `Vector3` default comparison already has approximation, you probably don't need it, also your method implies calling `Sqrt`, which may be expensive if you have lots of objects. You may also use `Vector3.SqrDistance(a, b)` or `(a - b).sqrMagnitude`, though I'm not sure about the first variant.
Don't call that `GetComponent(string)`, instead check `d != null`, probably even `d?.Damage(1)` if you use C# 6.
And something strange with the line `target.position * -1.0`, what should it do?

Comment: Why `GetComponent("Damageable") as Damageable` in one place and `GetComponent<Damageable>()` in the other?

Comment: @Draco18s, that wasn't done by design, was probably just in my many attempts to try solve the problem. Do you think the casting is the problem here?

Comment: Not likely. But you'll want to fix that anyway. Using strings to reference something with a known Type is not a good idea. One, there's a ton of Reflection overhead and two it means its harder to refactor.

Comment: you should atleast use a type instead of a string: `GetComponent(typeof(Damageable))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> coll

I guess this is short for collision, collision happens on 2 rigidbodies (or another static collider, but unrelated to the question), so when the bullet hit the enemy, it also block the enemy's path, even if you destroy it immediately the enemy will still stop moving for 1 frame.

So make the collider on the bullet to be a trigger, a trigger won't block other rigidbodies.

Use `OnTriggerEnter2D` (or `OnTriggerEnter(Collider)` for 3D game) to receive touch event.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag != "Player")
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);

        var d = other.GetComponent<Damageable>();
        if(d != null)
            d.Damage(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: "I guess this is short for collision" - close. Collided, as in .. "the other collided object than this". Your answer sounds like a good solution. Going to try it out and get back to you.

Comment: This worked perfectly, almost. The only change that's needed to your script is the change the function to OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other). I'm going to accept your answer, but please change that for future readers.

Comment: Sorry, my first impression for unity is a 3D engine, I didn't realize it is also working for 2D now.